# How can I spawn food in my SnakeGame on a field that is not occupied by either snake or a barrier?

Tags: java

How can I extend my spawnFood() method in my SnakeGame to create a new Food object on a field not occupied by Snake or Barrier.

```
private void spawnFood() {
    int x = (int) (Math.random() * numRows + 1);
    int y = (int) (Math.random() * numColumns +1);

    food = new Food(x , y);
}
```

Comment: Hi, what's your playfield? Please provide a working minimal example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to calculate a random free field, rather than calculating any random field and then check, if it's free. You could do that, but ultimately it would perform badly later on, when the field is filled up more and more. While your code is inexpensive, and therefore this would not be a dramatic problem, it is not ideal, and the best way to do it (which you probably need anyway to calculate the victory condition) is to calculate the free fields, and then find the first free one:

```
public Food spawnFood() {
    int width = numColumns - 2; // assuming borders on both ends.
    int height = numRows - 2; // assuming borders on both ends.
    int numFields = width * height;
    int freeSpaces = numField - getSnakeLength(); // I assume this method, because I don't know how your code works in regards to the Snake object.

    int freeFieldIndex = (int) Math.round(Math.random() * freeSpaces);
    for (int row = 0; freeFieldIndex >= 0; ++row) {
        int snakeFieldsInRow = getNumSnakeFieldsInRow(row); // The number of fields the snake takes up in that row.
        int unoccupiedInRow = width - snakeFieldsInRow;
        if (freeFieldIndex < unoccupiedInRow ) {
            int column = 0;
            while(; freeFieldIndex > 0; ++column) {
                if (!isSnakeField(row, column + 1)) { // This method must decide, whether a field is occupied by the snake.
                    --freeFieldIndex;
                }
            }

            return new Food(row, column);
        }
        freeFieldIndex -= unoccupiedInRow;
    }
    return null;
}
```

I didn't run this, since I lack the rest of the code, so it might need a bit of tweaking.

I know there are a bunch of methods I assumed, but since we don't know enough, I had to assume a lot. Hope this helps.